# Building my project sets the database to read only?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sqlite, installation

I have developed a program in Visual Studio using VB that connects to a .db database.
When I debug it, it works fine as the database on my computer is not set to read only (I checked by right clicking the file and going to properties).

I use the standard Visual Studio set up project to build it and the read only property of the database in the set up project is set to false.
However when I build the project and install it on another machine, the database somehow gets set to read only and I get the error "Attempt to write a read-only database"

Does anybody know how I would go about solving this?
Thanks

Edit: Hmm I have just checked and the folder that the database and other program files gets added to is marked as "Read only (only applies to files in the folder)". So whilst the database is not marked as read only, the folder is. Perhaps because it is in the program files folder?

Comment: Did you install your application in c:\program files or c:\program files (x86) and your database is in the same folder?

Comment: The program installed to c:\program files and the database is in the same folder, which I think is what the problem is.

I have been reading online, should the database be in an AppData folder or something like that?

Comment: Yes the problem is in this folder. Because the Operating system doesn't allows to write files there. You could change the location of your database file. I will give you a possible solution as an answer

Comment: When I add a folder in the set up, I right click on the file system bit and the only option is "Add a special folder" which gives me a long list of different types of folders I can choose from, do you know which type I should choose?

Comment: OK, select `Custom Folder` then set the property DefaultLocation to the custom string [CommonAppDataFolder]. I will explain better in the answer

Comment: Ok so following the steps in the answer you gave ended up with the database being added to 'C:\ProgramData' does that sound right?

That has also made my database read only due to it being in a read only folder?

Comment: No, I forget to say that the ProgramData is a common base folder for every application, so it is better to create a subfolder for your own application data

Comment: Yeah I guessed you forgot to mention that as the first time I did it, I though that creating the new custom folder would add a folder there automatically which it didn't so my connection string didn't work.

Anyway, I then set it to make a folder in there called "KeyCount" (the name of my application) however as you can see in [this imgur screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/xcYpc8Y.png) the KeyCount folder has for some reason also been automatically set to read only

Comment: Fix the connection string and then try the application. That folder is not readonly (by the way, if you look at every folder on your PC you will see the same dimmed checkbox)

Comment: Oh yes I didn't realise it was checked like that on every folder.

I fixed the connection string but it still gives me the same "Attempt to write a read-only database" that it gave me when it was in the program files folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folders `C:\PROGRAM FILES` or `C:\PROGRAM FILES (x86)` are configured by the operating system (Vista and after), for security reasons, to block write operations.
The recommended folder for writing application wide data (settings or database data files) can be retrieved calling `Environment.GetSpecialFolder` using the parameter `CommonApplicationData` of [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum.

The standard setup tool used in Visual Studio 2010 has no predefined folder that points to this `CommonApplicationData` directly, however you could use a workaround:

- Right click on the File System, select `Add a Special Folder` and
  then `Custom folder`
- Give a name to the new folder in the File System Tree
- Set the property `DefaultLocation` to `[CommonAppDataFolder]`
- Create a subfolder for your application with a right click on the new
  added folder Custom Folder
- Use this folder to add your database file.

After this, do not forget to change your application ConnectionString and point it to the new location of the file.  In C# you write something like this

```
string commonData = ENvironment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
string pathToDBFile = Path.Combine(commonData, "MyAppDir", "MyDB.sqlite");
```

Comment: For me, it's now read-only for the User, but for Administrators, it's a normal file.